# Why isn't my Initiation Station character showing up for download in the game?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I took a couple hours last night to make my Saints Row: The Third character in the Initiation Station so she'd be ready to go when I received the game. I'm in character creation now, and there's an option to download your character. However, my character isn't showing up as an option for download.

She's showing up on my Saints Row profile and is visible there. Why can't I get her into the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have any character be downloadable for use in the game, whether you've created it or just downloaded it from the website, you need to place them into your download queue.

- Go to your profile on the [Saints Row website](http://www.saintsrow.com/)
- Click on `Upload`
- You'll see a tab for `Your Created Characters`, which it should go to by default
- Click on the small thumbnail of your character
- It should show you a full body shot of your character with a large `Add to Queue` button on the right
- Click the button

Your character should then be downloadable in the character creator. You do not have to restart character creation in order to download a character from the website. I had it open already and was successfully able to download after waiting a few moments.